# Mouse Pointer Jumps About in Ubuntu 20.04 (dual-boot with Windows 10)

Tags: mouse, 20.04, mouse-pointer

Now that I have loaded Ubuntu 20.04 to dual-boot on a Packard Bell with Windows 10 Home 64-bit, I am unable to stop the mouse pointer from jumping around and leaving a trail of flickering pointers wherever the pointer has gone. When I hover over a button, the pointer jumps around so much, clicking on a button becomes very much a hit and miss affair. Meanwhile, an unmoving pointer sits at the bottom right of the screen, while I am moving a second pointer around the screen. How do I fix this please? Is it a mouse driver compatibility issue?

This is the result of my xinput:

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal

$ xinput
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ USB Wired Keyboard Consumer Control       id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ PixArt USB Optical Mouse                  id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ USB Wired Keyboard                        id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ USB Wired Keyboard System Control         id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ USB Wired Keyboard Consumer Control       id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

I'm shooting in the dark here. I've unplugged the USB mouse and, after plugging it back in, there was no change. I have also done a download because someone said that this worked for his touchpad when his mouse pointer was dancing around after upgrading to Ubuntu 20.04. It worked for him, but it doesn't work for me.

This is what I downloaded:

```
$ sudo apt install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
```

So, it looks as though I'll have to uninstall that.

```
$ sudo apt-get remove xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
```

After removing it I have the following message:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'xserver-xorg-input-synaptics' is not installed, so not removed
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-5.4.0-26 linux-headers-5.4.0-26-generic linux-image-5.4.0-26-generic
  linux-modules-5.4.0-26-generic linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-26-generic
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 129 not to upgrade.
```

So, I have autoremoved the packages no longer required. It has not changed anything. I have unplugged the mouse from a USB 3 and plugged it into a USB 2 with no effect.
Let's have a look at the output of:

```
lsb_release -a; uname -a; lsusb
```

The output is:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
Linux charlesb2t-iMedia-S2984 5.4.0-37-generic #41-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jun 3 18:57:02 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:0153 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 3-in-1 (SD/SDHC/SDXC) Card Reader
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 0461:4e6f Primax Electronics, Ltd Acer Wired Keyboard Model KBAY211
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 0461:4e70 Primax Electronics, Ltd USB Optical Mouse
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Is the Primax Electronics Ltd USB Optical Mouse incompatible with Ubuntu?

I have noticed that in the  [Linux USB IDs](http://www.linux-usb.org/usb.ids) the following list:

```
0461  Primax Electronics, Ltd
    0010  HP PR1101U / Primax PMX-KPR1101U Keyboard
    0300  G2-300 Scanner
    0301  G2E-300 Scanner
    0302  G2-300 #2 Scanner
    0303  G2E-300 #2 Scanner
    0340  Colorado 9600 Scanner
    0341  Colorado 600u Scanner
    0345  Visioneer 6200 Scanner
    0346  Memorex Maxx 6136u Scanner
    0347  Primascan Colorado 2600u/Visioneer 4400 Scanner
    0360  Colorado 19200 Scanner
    0361  Colorado 1200u Scanner
    0363  VistaScan Astra 3600(ENG)
    0364  LG Electronics Scanworks 600U Scanner
    0365  VistaScan Astra 3600(ENG)
    0366  6400
    0367  VistaScan Astra 3600(ENG)
    0371  Visioneer Onetouch 8920 Scanner
    0374  UMAX Astra 2500
    0375  VistaScan Astra 3600(ENG)
    0377  Medion MD 5345 Scanner
    0378  VistaScan Astra 3600(ENG)
    037b  Medion MD 6190 Scanner
    037c  VistaScan Astra 3600(ENG)
    0380  G2-600 Scanner
    0381  ReadyScan 636i Scanner
    0382  G2-600 #2 Scanner
    0383  G2E-600 Scanner
    038a  UMAX Astra 3000/3600
    038b  Xerox 2400 Onetouch
    038c  UMAX Astra 4100
    0392  Medion/Lifetec/Tevion/Cytron MD 6190
    03a8  9420M
    0813  IBM UltraPort Camera
    0815  Micro Innovations IC200 Webcam
    0819  Fujifilm IX-30 Camera [webcam mode]
    081a  Fujifilm IX-30 Camera [storage mode]
    081c  Elitegroup ECS-C11 Camera
    081d  Elitegroup ECS-C11 Storage
    0a00  Micro Innovations Web Cam 320
    4d01  Comfort Keyboard / Kensington Orbit Elite
    4d02  Mouse-in-a-Box
    4d03  Kensington Mouse-in-a-box
    4d04  Mouse
    4d06  Balless Mouse (HID)
    4d0f  HP Optical Mouse
    4d15  Dell Optical Mouse
    4d17  Optical Mouse
    4d20  HP Optical Mouse
    4d2a  PoPo Elixir Mouse (HID)
    4d2b  Wireless Laser Mini Mouse (HID)
    4d2c  PoPo Mini Pointer Mouse (HID)
    4d2e  Optical Mobile Mouse (HID)
    4d51  0Y357C PMX-MMOCZUL (B) [Dell Laser Mouse]
    4d62  HP Laser Mobile Mini Mouse
    4d75  Rocketfish RF-FLBTAD Bluetooth Adapter
    4d81  Dell N889 Optical Mouse
    4d8a  HP Multimedia Keyboard
    4d91  Laser mouse M-D16DL
    4d92  Optical mouse M-D17DR
    4db1  Dell Laptop Integrated Webcam 2Mpix
    4de3  HP 5-Button Optical Comfort Mouse
    4de7  webcam
    4e04  Lenovo Keyboard KB1021
    4e22  Dell Mouse, 2 Buttons, Modell: MS111-P
    4e6f  Acer Wired Keyboard Model KBAY211
```

The **4e70 USB Optical Mouse** is not listed. Could this be my issue?

To try and answer this I dug up a Xenta Wireless Optical Mouse, but the problem of one jittery mouse pointer, which I can move around, and a second stationary mouse pointer in the bottom right of the screen still persists.

```
$ lsb_release -a; uname -a; lsusb
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
Linux charlesb2t-iMedia-S2984 5.4.0-37-generic #41-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jun 3 18:57:02 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:0153 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 3-in-1 (SD/SDHC/SDXC) Card Reader
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0461:4e6f Primax Electronics, Ltd Acer Wired Keyboard Model KBAY211
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 1d57:0008 Xenta 2.4G Wireless Optical Mouse
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

I have checked the Packard Bell website to see whether the BIOS is up to date and it looks as though it is. Nothing has changed since I bought the machine in 2016.

After I have the input list:

```
$ xinput --list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ USB Wired Keyboard Consumer Control       id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ PixArt USB Optical Mouse                  id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ USB Wired Keyboard System Control         id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ USB Wired Keyboard Consumer Control       id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ USB Wired Keyboard                        id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

I can get a list of properties:

```
$ xinput --list-props "PixArt USB Optical Mouse"
Device 'PixArt USB Optical Mouse':
    Device Enabled (161):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (163): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled (298):   0
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled Default (299):   0
    libinput Scroll Methods Available (300):    0, 0, 1
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled (301):   0, 0, 0
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled Default (302):   0, 0, 0
    libinput Button Scrolling Button (303): 2
    libinput Button Scrolling Button Default (304): 2
    libinput Middle Emulation Enabled (305):    0
    libinput Middle Emulation Enabled Default (306):    0
    libinput Accel Speed (307): -0.014706
    libinput Accel Speed Default (308): 0.000000
    libinput Accel Profiles Available (309):    1, 1
    libinput Accel Profile Enabled (310):   1, 0
    libinput Accel Profile Enabled Default (311):   1, 0
    libinput Left Handed Enabled (312): 0
    libinput Left Handed Enabled Default (313): 0
    libinput Send Events Modes Available (283): 1, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled (284):    0, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled Default (285):    0, 0
    Device Node (286):  "/dev/input/event6"
    Device Product ID (287):    1121, 20080
    libinput Drag Lock Buttons (314):   <no items>
    libinput Horizontal Scroll Enabled (315):   1
```

However, I don't think any changes can be made there that will fix the problem.

As the **4e70 USB Optical Mouse** is not listed, in the [Linux USB IDs List](http://www.linux-usb.org/usb.ids), but the [Kensington](https://www.kensington.com/en-gb/p/products/control/mice/mouse-in-a-box-wired/) **4d03 Mouse-in-a-box** is, I'm going to try and get my hands on one of those.

Comment: So, I've now plugged in a "Kensington Mouse-in-a-Box" Wired Optical USB Mouse and the PC has identified it as a ***093a:2510 Pixart Imaging, Inc. Optical Mouse*** (not 4d03 Mouse-in-a-box), but the mouse is on the Linux USB IDs List. However, this different mouse is still showing the same behaviour of jumping the mouse-pointer about; leaving a trail of flickering mouse-pointers wherever one has passed the mouse-pointer; and then there's still another stationary mouse-pointer at the bottom-right of the screen. So, what now?

Comment: The issue seems to be that I have two monitors plugged in to my tower. If only one monitor is plugged in, the mouse-pointer performs perfectly. However, I need two screens / monitors for my work.

Answer (score 0):

So, all I've solved here is:

1. It's not down to a dual-boot setup with Windows 10 and Ubuntu 20.04
2. It's not down to an incompatible mouse driver

However, the problem of the jumping mouse-pointer occurs as soon as I connect another monitor to my PC - https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/display-dual-monitors.html